# Is there any way to show desktop mode page in mobile device?

Tags: browser-detection

I'm trying to open a page(not the one I created) in a desktop version in mobile device by iframe.

Is there any way to do it?

The page i'm trying to open in an iframe automatically detects mobile device and opens in mobile mode. 
It doesnt have to be iframe.

I just want to know if there is any way to fake that it is an mobile device.

Comment: for testing? just override the mobile detection code. `$mobile = false` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The website (which you haven't created) is detecting that you are using a mobile device in one of two ways:

**1. User agent detection**

Your best bet is to override the user agent, sent by the mobile browser with one that is used by a desktop browser (e.g. Firefox). There are many addons for the desktop browsers that allow you to spoof your user agent, so I guess there should be some mobile browsers/addons that will allow you to do it as well. However, you haven't mentioned your device (Android, iPhone or Windows Mobile), so you will have to Google for this specifically.

**2. Feature detection**

Simply put, the website uses JavaScript to check if the browser supports a given feature (e.g. an animation or a custom event). Since most mobile devices have limited functionality - they do not support all features, provided by desktop browsers. As such, the JavaScript check may redirect you to another page or provide a different layout, based on the result of the check. There is no way to override this, since you can't modify the mobile browser to add new features. Your only bet is to use a more modern phone or browser.